# Use a nested struct members directly

Tags: c++, discriminated-union

So I'm trying to nest a struct into another one by value, but I want to be able to import the members of the nested structs as if they are direct members of Generic struct. There seems to be a using keywork in C++, but it doesn't work as I would have expected.

For example:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    // some specific A stuff
};
struct B
{
    float a;
    // some specific B stuff
};

template<typename T>
struct Generic
{
    Kind kind; // an enum or an integer ID that allow to figure out what type is contained
    // some generic stuff

    // how to do this?
    using T t; // Error: a class-qualified name is required

    // some more generic stuff
};

void foo()
{
    Generic<B> g;
    g.t.a = 6.7 // we can do this with regular struct field
    g.a = 5.4; // but need to be able to do this
}
```

This construct is made in this way to be able to create different user-extensible views into some differently-sized item buffer, where each item is a tagged union with custom contents and common header and footer.

So the main question: How to import ("use") some struct into a different one and be able to access the nested struct' fields directly?

Comment: The only way is to inherit from `T`.

Comment: `template<typename T> struct Generic : public T { ... };`

Comment: This does indeed seem like you want inheritance. ***But*** perhaps that's not the correct design choice? Remember that inheritance is an "is-a" relationship. Is `Generic<B>` (for example) an `B`? Should it be?  Perhaps the relationship should be *composition*, where you define the structure as a normal member variable? Perhaps you should really use one of the standard classes, like `std::variant` or similar?

Comment: To be able to help you properly, you need to tell us the actual and underlying problem your `Generic` template is supposed to solve. Otherwise this question is just an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Always ask about the actual and underlying problem directly, not to help with one possible (of maybe many) solutions to (for us) the unknown problem.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How would inheritance work? If I inherit a struct, it will put T in the beginning, and there would be no way to access `kind` field or any others that have to be a known offset from the beginning of the struct.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're solving in the first place. What do you need this for?

Comment: @yuraSniper: You could put `kind` in another, earlier base class, although you wouldn’t actually be able to access it via a union without knowing the real type (and without undefined behavior).

Comment: "This construct is made in this way to be able to create different user-extensible views into some differently-sized item buffer, where each item is a tagged union with custom contents and common header and footer." - It is just one serious problem that I hit recently, but there are many other examples - like controlling the struct layout in case of multiple inheritance(by doing it a bit manually) etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possible way to work around the problem by using inheritance, but it needs more structures:

```
// The "data" structures
struct A { ... };
struct B { ... };

// Common "header" structure
struct Header { ... };

// The "generic" structure to combine the header with the data
template<typename D>
struct Data : Header, D
{
    // Empty
};
```

Now you can use the `B` data as

```
Data<B> data;
```

The header information will come first, the actual data follow. And the size will depend on the data structure.

But please note that from a design point of view, this is highly dubious. I would prefer actual composition:

```
struct A
{
    // Actual A data fields follow
};

struct Data_A
{
    Header header;
    A data;
};
```

This allows you to read the header and data separately from the buffer. It's also more explicit about the separation of the header and the data, and should make the code clearer and easier to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Does C++ guarantee the layout? Meaning that the base class objects will appear in memory in the order thay are in the list?

Comment: Also while it may look dubious, making the user compose their structs with headers increases friction of the interface. The user may want to use the structs A&B directly, so they will have to create an additional structs that compose their A&B with header, which is quite annoying :)

Comment: @yuraSniper They layout is actually ABI-dependent. But with the [IA64 ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) (which is used for example Linux) the inherited subobjects are in the declared order.

Comment: @yuraSniper And you mention "users" a lot. Who are these "users"? Normal and decently experienced programmers shouldn't really have a problem with normal nested structures. Especially if they have used binary protocols or files before.